# rails validation uniqueness with respect to associated column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to validate model column with respect to associated column

app/models/filter.rb

```
belongs_to :filter_set
validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: %i[filter_set.organization_id]
```

app/models/filter_set.rb

```
has_many :filters
```

I want to add validation on filter type with respect to associated organization_id . I can't find anything to do validation of association key

Comment: validates_uniqueness_of can only be used to set conditions based on *this* models table. What you're trying to do would require a join. What this problem really should be telling you is that you're not modeling the data correctly - you're most likely missing a join table between filters and filter_sets that would let you use filters as a normalization table. You need to remember that an application level validations are very prone to race conditions and need to be enforced with a database constaint which would be very difficult with whatever you have here.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that with belongs_to, this filter can only belong_to one filter_set, so:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :filter_set_id }
```

will do the trick